# Can not deselect from MUI select Component. What's the right way?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement deselect option in material UI select component.My question is 'is there any prop that automatically deselect the selected object after clicking the selected Object?'

my code snippet:

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>{t('typeUsers')}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    label={t('typeUsers')}
    value={filterUser}
    onChange={(e) => { setFilterUser(e.target.value); }}
  >
   {Object.values(users).filter((user) => (user.administrator === false)).map((user) => (<MenuItem key={user.id} value={user.id}>{user.name}</MenuItem>))}
 </Select>
</FormControl>
```

OR how can I add an additional MenuItem that sets selected Item deslected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following menu item above where you iterate through `users`

```
<MenuItem key='clear' value='clear'>Clear selection</MenuItem>
```

And here is the `onChange` for the `Select` component

```
onChange={e => setFilterUser(e.target.value === 'clear' ? '' : e.target.value)}
```

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>{t('typeUsers')}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    label={t('typeUsers')}
    value={filterUser}
    onChange={e => setFilterUser(e.target.value === 'clear' ? '' : e.target.value)}
  >
   <MenuItem key='clear' value='clear'>Clear selection</MenuItem>
   {Object.values(users).filter((user) => (user.administrator === false)).map((user) => (<MenuItem key={user.id} value={user.id}>{user.name}</MenuItem>))}
 </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: should I add onClick prop along with onChange? Let's say I have a selected value I want to deselect the value while I click the selected value again.

Comment: BTW i don't want to add any extra button or stuff. just want to click the selected value for deselecting. Thats all. IDK MUI select component does work in that way or not!!

Comment: @cosmic `onChange={(e) => setFilterUser(previousFilterUser => previousFilterUser === e.target.value ? null : e.target.value)} `

Comment: That seemed correct but didn't work. @Anatol

Comment: i defined `const [filterUser, setFilterUser] = useState(' ')` like this. instead `null` used (' '). also didn't work.

Comment: Does onChange not get called when clicking on an already selected item? @cosmic you can check with a console.log

Comment: NOP onChange is not getting called. I placed console.log right after `previousFilterUser === e.target.value ? ` this condition

Comment: check How My menuItem is getting values. How could I add additional menuItem like this? @Anatol

Comment: @cosmic I am glad it’s working! I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark near it :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the onChange event doesn't fire if the user selects an item that's currently selected, as you found. I got around this by adding an onClick handler to the menu item and comparing its value to the current selection value, then setting the selection to undefined if they match.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an hack, but it worked for me: I assigned an additional onClick handler to the MenuItem element, then listened for `clickEvent.target.selected === true` to check if the same item has been clicked while active.

If using typescript the handler could be something like this:

```
onClick={ (clickEvent) => {
  if ((clickEvent.target as HTMLOptionElement).selected === true) {
    // do my stateful reset
  }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering on your "Clear selection" MenuItem with an empty value.

```
{filterUser && (<MenuItem value=""><em>Clear selection</em></MenuItem>)}
```

This way, "clear selection" will be shown only if you have selected any option. Here's your fixed code:

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>{t("typeUsers")}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    label={t("typeUsers")}
    value={filterUser}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setFilterUser(e.target.value);
    }}>
    {filterUser && (
      <MenuItem value="">
        <em>Clear selection</em>
      </MenuItem>
    )}
    {Object.values(users)
      .filter((user) => user.administrator === false)
      .map((user) => (
        <MenuItem key={user.id} value={user.id}>
          {user.name}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ran to the same issue recently, and I have found the solution is rather easy. my solution is to add an additional MenuItem inside the select and simply include a "None" or "Clear" option and give it an empty string in the value.
it looks like this using your code:-

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>{t('typeUsers')}</InputLabel>
  <Select
    label={t('typeUsers')}
    value={filterUser}
    onChange={(e) => { setFilterUser(e.target.value); }}
  >
    {/* Option for clearing the selection */}
    <MenuItem value="">
      <em>None</em>
    </MenuItem>

    {/* Other user options */}
    {Object.values(users).filter((user) => (user.administrator === false)).map((user) => (
      <MenuItem key={user.id} value={user.id}>
        {user.name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

When this option is selected, the value will be an empty string i.e nothing selected! Hope it helps.